# Can JaCoCo be used for NodeJS code coverage?

Tags: node.js, jacoco

I know there are number of tools available for Node JS code coverage testing. But I want to know if it is possible to integrate JaCoCo with Node JS for code coverage generation. If possible how can I do that?

Comment: suspect you need to contact SonarCloud, of course, if you use a paid subscription